# C++: repeated call of system()

Tags: c++, c++11

I need some help with external program call from c++ code.

I have to call `javap.exe` (from JDK package) from my program many times (probably more than 100), but call `system("javap.exe some_parameters")` is extremely slow. It's work so good for one set of parameters but repeated calls of `system()` not acceptable. I think it is only because of costs to access the hard disk and application run (but I'm not sure).

What can I do for better performance? Can I "save `javap.exe` in RAM" and call it "directly".
Or may be somebody knows how can I get java-class description and methods signature without `javap.exe`?

Comment: Would it be an option to have a *persistent* Java instance, and communicating via JNI calls / callbacks? (It can certainly be done this way, the question is if it would be acceptable for you or if you *need* a wholly different Java instance each time.)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. I just don't have many Java-experiences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Java VM is not cheap to start running, and it's likely that its initialization is eating up the lion's share of your time. Luckily, the functionality of `javap` is available directly through Java code. I suggest that you write a small Java application which, while similar to `javap`, does with one invocation what you would otherwise need thousands for. (Though... maybe you could already use just one? javap *will* take multiple class files, after all...)

Answer (score -1):

Calling `system()` is easy, but very inefficient, primarily because you are not just launching whatever program you specify. Rather, you are launching one process (a shell), and that shell will examine your parameter and launch a second process.

If you're on a system that supports `fork()` and `exec*()`, you're going to improve performance by using them instead. As a pseudo-code example, consider:

```
void replace_system(const char *command)
{
    pid_t child = fork();
    if (child < 0) {
        perror("fork:");
        return;
    }

    if (child) {
        /* this is the parent, wait for the child to finish */
        while (waitpid(child, &status, options) <= 0);
        return;
    }

    /* this is the new process */
    exec*(...);
    perror("failed to start the child");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Choose one of the exec* functions based on how you want to arrange the parameters. You'll need to break your string of arguments into components, and possibly provide an environment of your liking. Once you call the exec* function, that function will never return (unless there is an error starting the command you've defined for it).

Beyond performance considerations, another reason to use this is, if desired, it allows you to modify the child's standard paths. For example, you might be interested in the output of a child; if you modify its stdout to be a pipe available to you, you can simply read what it prints. Research source code for the standard `popen()` call to find an example of this.

Comment: Agreed that `fork`/`exec` will be more efficient than `system`. But compared to all the JVM setup, I doubt that the overhead of going through the shell is more than a blip in the total runtime.

Comment: @Sneftel I agree (and have upvoted your answer). Even though in the signal-to-noise ratio, JVM startup time is signal to system()'s noise, the OP states he's calling system() perhaps more than 100 times; that's a lot of magnification of noise.

Comment: If expensive = 1000 * (large + small), you **ignore** small.  Any optimization of small is premature while large exists.  If expensive = large + huge*(small), then small optimization may not be premature.  In the above case, you are telling the OP to optimize small when the OP should be ignoring that problem (optimization of small) completely.  Any effort towards it while large exists is wasteful (assuming large is much larger than small).

Comment: @Yakk so in your opinion (and based on what I assume was your down vote), such a suggestion should never be made... got it! I'll have to respectfully disagree though; In my opinion the existence of a solution to (large) does not mean that (small) should be ignored forever.